# android: error on SQLiteDatabase rawQuery (fetching data)

Tags: android, sqlite

So I have a SQliteDatabase mDb. It only has one column, and its data are Strings for previously saved inputs. I'm trying to populate all the data from mDb into a String[] for AutoCompleteTextView (so that the autocomplete is based on previous inputs), and here's my code to get all of the String.

```
public String[] fetchAllSearch() {
 ArrayList<String> allSearch = new ArrayList<String>();
 Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery("select * from " + DATABASE_TABLE, null);
 c.moveToFirst();
 if (c.getCount() > 0) {
  do {
   allSearch.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("KEY")));
  } while (c.moveToNext());
 }
 String[] foo = (String[]) allSearch.toArray();
 if (foo == null) {
  foo = new String[] {""};
 }

 return foo;
}
```

my CREATE_TABLE command is

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE;
..

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }
```

But for some reason the line mDb.rawQuery(...) is giving me "no such table found" exception, and for the life of me I can't figure out why. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the value of `DATABASE_TABLE`?

If it is just a table name, then the create statement is incomplete because it doesn't specify the columns.

If it is a name plus column definitions, then the select will not work.

So, you need to use different text in the two places you used `DATABASE_TABLE`

Try using the SQLite3 command line program to try out your SQL. E.g.,

```
sqlite> create table foo;
Error: near ";": syntax error
sqlite> create table foo(col);
sqlite> select * from foo(col);
Error: near "(": syntax error
sqlite>
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah my create statement was missing columns, definitely too late at night to keep working

Answer (score 0):

Use `SELECT column_name FROM table_name`.

Avoid using `*` in the query as it might cause the problem related to primary key.